# Need help in opening an email from the inbox and taking a screenshot of it using SELENIUM RC

Tags: selenium-rc

I could able to login to ISPs, gmail in particular. Now i need to open an email from the inbox and taking a screenshot of it using SELENIUM RC.

Please suggest with some examples.

thnx,
Bharath

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. What results did you get? 3. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? (please be more specific, these are not self-evident from the current state of your question) Also, GMail is not an Internet Service Provider (an ISP provides you with a data pipe between you and the internet, GMail is a part of the traffic that flows along that pipe), that confuses me a bit - care to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Use `selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot()` method, where selenium is your DefaultSelenium instance.